# Hard table row swapping, parent of swapped row is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, swap

I have 2 types of tables and I want to exchange rows between the 2.
One is like:

```
<table>
 <tr class="aTable">
  <td>
</table>
```

and the other:

```
<table class="bTable">
 <tr>
  <td>
</table>
```

The reason of this different form is that i have *multiple instances* of `aTable` on the **left side**, from which i need to select one row to be swapped with a row of *one* `bTable` on the **right side**.

So I must select 1 row from any of the multiple `aTable` tables on the left side, highlight it red, select 1 row from the right side `bTable`, highlight it green, and click "swap" to call the `swapFunction()`

I use the following code to highlight the specific row each time

```
$('.aTable').on('click', function(event) {
   if($(this).hasClass("highlightred")){

      $(this).toggleClass('highlightred');

   }else{

      $('.aTable').each(function(idx, elm) {

          $('.aTable').removeClass('highlightred');

      });

      $(this).toggleClass('highlightred');
   }
});

$('.bTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {

    $(this).toggleClass('highlightgreen')
           .siblings().removeClass('highlightgreen');

});
```

and the following function to swap:

```
function swapFunction() {

        var sourceRow = $('.bTable tbody tr.highlightgreen').removeClass('highlightgreen').toggleClass('aTable').eq(0);
        var targetRow = $('tbody tr.aTable.highlightred').removeClass('highlightred').removeClass('aTable').eq(0);

        sourceRow.after(targetRow.clone());
        targetRow.replaceWith(sourceRow);
};
```

Everything works ok, if i do the swap once, but if i try to swap back these rows, the `targetRow` cannot be highlighted thus selected, and the `sourceRow` seems to get both classes of `highlightred` and `highlightgreen`. i print `targetRow` parent() and appears to be `null` after the switch, whereas the `sourceRow` parent() appears fine ... anyone has any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see multiple problems with just the top piece of code. Here's a better way to do it:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3AvEq/)

First, don't use the classes inconsistently. You're giving the class "bTable" to a table, but "aTable" to a row in a table. It's confusing. Just use it on tables. Here's how I'd set up the HTML:

```
<table class="aTable myTable"> <tr> <td> </td> </tr> </table>
<table class="bTable myTable"> <tr> <td> </td> </tr> </table>
```

Now for a little code consolidation:

```
$('.myTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {

    var cl;

    if ($(this).parents('.myTable').hasClass('aTable')) cl = 'highlightred';
    else cl = 'highlightgreen';

    if($(this).hasClass(cl)) {
        $(this).removeClass(cl);
    } else {
        $('.' + cl).removeClass(cl);
        $(this).addClass(cl);
    }
});
```

Now for your swapFunction():

```
function swapFunction() {

    var sourceRow = $('.bTable tbody tr.highlightgreen').removeClass('highlightgreen');
    var targetRow = $('.aTable tbody tr.highlightred').removeClass('highlightred');
    sourceRow.after(targetRow.clone());
    targetRow.replaceWith(sourceRow);

};
```

This may need adjustments to completely fit what you're looking for, but it should do most of the job.

Comment: well i was thinking that aTable was a broad table consisting of smaller ones and gave that name, but u are right that it was inconsistent

Comment: thanks for this, i checked and it works ok with very few adjustments!

Comment: my code was a royal mess... i dont know well most jquery functions and i keep adjusting other people's code from stackoverflow. suckkk..

Comment: $('.' + cl).removeClass(cl) could u explain further that line?